Android webview close automatically when capture image from camera
I have used WebView camera for capture image but in Android 14 when capture 2-3 images one by one then on click OK button in camera WebView close automatically and also not showing any error or log.
How can I investigate this?
private void openImageChooser(ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback) {
    if (mUMA != null) {
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
    }
    mUMA = filePathCallback;
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Image file creation failed", ex);
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireActivity(), requireActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile));
        } else {
            takePictureIntent = null;
        }
    }
    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
    Intent[] intentArray;
    if (takePictureIntent != null) {
        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
    } else {
        intentArray = new Intent[0];
    }

    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    try {
        IntentResult Result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Result != null) {
            if (Result.getContents() != null) {
                //textView.setText(""+Result.getContents());
                String message = Result.getContents();
                Log.i("webviewscan", "qr-->" + message);

                mwebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: " + "updateQRcode(" + message + ")", null);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == Constant.RESULT_TEXT) {
            if (intent != null) {
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
                mwebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: " + "updateFromNative(\"" + message + "\")", null);
            }
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            try {
                Uri[] results = null;
                //Check if response is positive
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == FCR) {
                        if (null == mUMA) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (intent == null) {
                            //Capture Photo if no image available
                            if (mCM != null) {
                                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                            }
                        } else {
                            String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                            if (dataString != null) {
                                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
                mUMA = null;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i("webview_crash","--"+ex.toString());
            }
        } else {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.i("webview_crash","--"+ex.toString());
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}


anyone please help me
